# Можно ли получить из api яндекс карт точку пересечения границы страны?

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Есть задача - рассчитать стоимость маршрута на автомобиле из точки A в точку B.
Известно: Расход автомобиля, тип топлива, расстояние от точки A до точки B.
Но проблема заключается, в том, что стоимость бензина например в России и условной Франции разная.

Comment: Уточните, в чем же вопрос, в заголовке или в том что вы в конце написали? (отредактируйте плиз)

Comment: Эм.. А ты бензин прям в точке пересечения границы собрался покупать?

Answer (score 2):

Встроенного метода в API Яндекс.Карт для нахождения точки пересечения маршрутом границы нет. Самостоятельно это можно решить, либо проверив точки маршрута на вхождение в регион страны, либо прогнав точки через геокодер.

Первый вариант менее универсальный, поскольку [модуль регионов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions.html/?lang=ru) содержит полигоны не слишком высокой точности. Да и не всем нужны лишние полигоны на карте.

Второй требует дополнительного решения задачи минимизации запросов к геокодеру, поскольку маршрут Минск-Новосибирск, например, состоит из более 40000 точек, а ограничения бесплатного использования, да и здравый смысл говорят, что так нехорошо. Его решение примерно такое:

1. Строим маршрут и находим все точки его пути.
2. Бьём число точек пополам и запрашиваем от геокодера код страны в этой точке.
3. Сравниваем полученный от код с кодом стартовой точки
4. Повторяем с пункта 2, пока длина отрезка не уменьшится до 1. Так можно сократить количество запросов к геокодеру до 10-15 на маршрут.

Получение точек в массив **edge**:

```
ymaps.route(["Минск", "Вильнюс"]).then( // строим маршрут для последующей обработки
    function (res) {
        myMap.setBounds(res.properties.get('boundedBy'))
        myMap.geoObjects.add(res);
        // Объединим в выборку все сегменты маршрута.
        var pathsObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(res.getPaths())
        // Переберем все сегменты и разобьем их на отрезки.
        pathsObjects.each(function (path) {
            var coordinates = path.geometry.getCoordinates();
            for (var i = 1, l = coordinates.length; i < l; i++) {
                edges.push(coordinates[i]);
            }
        });
```

Функция определения кода страны в точке:

```
            function getCode(coords,i) { // определение кода страны в точке
                ymaps.geocode(coords, {results: 1})
                .then(function (res) {
                    var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0) // Выбираем первый результат геокодирования.
                        ccodeX = firstGeoObject.properties.get('metaDataProperty').GeocoderMetaData.Address.country_code; // код страны в точке
                        compareX(ccodeX)
                })
            }
```

Рабочий пример с точностью нахождения границы до одного элемента пути на jsfiddle:
https://jsbin.com/nocitotiju/edit?js,output